# Assembly, draw an image

Tags: c, gcc, assembly, dos, nasm

I need to draw QRCode via Assembly(intel)+C(c99) in DOS. But it seems I have too little memory for it.
I tried to store image as bit array:

```
image
db 11111110b,
...
```

But anyway I had no result(`Illegal read from 9f208c70, CS:IP      192:9f20734f`). Now I don't know what to do. Here is code I used:

module.asm:

```
[bits 16]

global setpixel
global setVM
global getch
global getPixelBlock

section .text

setVM:
        push bp
        mov bp, sp
        mov ax, [bp+6]
        mov ah, 0
        int 10h
        pop bp
ret

setpixel:
        push bp
        mov bp,sp
        xor bx, bx
        mov     cx, [bp+6]
        mov     dx, [bp+10]
        mov     al, [bp+14]
        mov ah, 0ch
        int 10h
        pop bp
ret

getch:
        push bp
        mov ah,0
        int 16h
        mov ah,0
        pop bp
ret

getPixelBlock:
        push bp
        mov cx, [bp+6]
        mov bx, image
        add bx, cx
        mov ax, [bx]
        pop bp
ret

section .data
image
db 11111110b,
db 10011011b,
db 11111100b,
db 00010011b,
db 00010000b,
db 01101110b,
db 10110000b,
db 10111011b,
db 01110101b,
db 01100101b,
db 11011011b,
db 10100000b,
db 00101110b,
db 11000001b,
db 01110001b,
db 00000111b,
db 11111010b,
db 10101111b,
db 11100000b,
db 00011000b,
db 00000000b,
db 11010011b,
db 01011111b,
db 01101011b,
db 11100100b,
db 11101000b,
db 00110101b,
db 11001111b,
db 01001111b,
db 11100000b,
db 00011011b,
db 11010001b,
db 00100111b,
db 00000011b,
db 10000000b,
db 00000011b,
db 10001111b,
db 11111010b,
db 00100000b,
db 01010000b,
db 01000110b,
db 01011011b,
db 10111010b,
db 01001111b,
db 01010101b,
db 11010110b,
db 10001110b,
db 00101110b,
db 10010001b,
db 01111011b,
db 00000101b,
db 01100001b,
db 10001111b,
db 11101110b,
db 11000001b
```

main.c:

```
__asm(".code16gcc\n");

int run();
int _start()
{
    return run();
} // Dirty hack to code as I used to

#include "ASM.inl"
#include "Painter.inl"

int run()
{
    setVM(0x10);
    _brushSize = 5;
     drawLogo(30,30);
    uint ret = (uint)getch();
    return ret>>5;
}
```

ASM.inl

```
#ifndef __ASM_H__
#define __ASM_H__

typedef unsigned short int uint;
typedef unsigned char uchar;

void setpixel(uint x, uint y, uint color);
void setVM(uint vm);
uchar getch();
uchar getPixelBlock(uchar);

#endif /* __ASM_H__ */
```

Painter.inl:

```
/**
  * You can create other colors by using bitwise or
  */
enum Color {
    White  = 0b0111,
    Black  = 0b0000,
    Red    = 0b0100,
    Green  = 0b0010,
    Blue   = 0b0001,
    Bright = 0b1000,
};

int _brushSize = 5;

void rect(uint x, uint y, uint width, uint height, uint color)
{
    uint i,j;
    for (i=x; i<width+x; i++) {
        for (j=y; j<height+y; j++) {
            setpixel(i,j,color);
        }
    }
}

uint getColor(uchar element, uchar offset)
{
    element = element & (1 << offset) >> offset;
    return element ? Black : White;
}

void drawLogo(uint x, uint y)
{
    uchar current;
    uchar counter = 0;
    for (uint i=0; i<21; i++) {
        for (uint j=0; j<21; j++) {
            counter = i*21+j;
            current = getPixelBlock((uchar)counter/8);
            rect(x+i*_brushSize, y+j*_brushSize, _brushSize, _brushSize, getColor(current, counter%8));
        }
    }
}
```

Compilation script:

```
#!/bin/bash
nasm -f elf32 module.asm -o module.o
gcc -std=c99 -m32 -ffreestanding -masm=intel -c main.c -o main.o
ld -m elf_i386 -Ttext=0x100 main.o module.o -o os.com
objcopy os.com -O binary
```

- GCC version: `4.8.3 (Gentoo 4.8.3 p1.1, pie-0.5.9)`
- NASM version: `2.11.05`
- DOSBox version: `0.74`

What I am doing wrong? Maybe I should write directly into graphic memory or something like that? Or maybe I should change gcc optimizations?

Comment: You must include code in your question if you want an answer -- links go stale in time. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve.

Comment: Do you actually know how to draw graphics in DOS?

Comment: @david.pfx Yep, I know how to draw graphics in DO via interrupts.

Comment: You might want to look into direct drawing into video memory.

Comment: @david.pfx I thought about this, but I think it won't solve problems with memory. Only way is to store data directly in graphic memory at the beginning(IMHO) or something like that.

Comment: Could the problem be that you are writing 16-bit code (`[bits 16]`) and linking it as 32-bit code (`gcc -m32`)?

Comment: How are you running the `os.com` file?  What's printing the `Illegal read` error message. The addresses given suggest the fault occurred in 32-bit protected mode, not in real mode or virtual 8086 mode.

Comment: @Jongware No, it can't be, or `ld` or `nasm` would warn about this. Also 16bit code is compatible with 32bit. And I compile asm as 32bit(`nasm -f elf32`)

Comment: Try changing the `core` DOSBox configuration variable to `normal`. It might give you a better error message at least.

Comment: @RossRidge Unfortunately it doesn't help, still dozens of `Illegal read from`.

Comment: Does the CS:IP address in the error message look more appropriate for real mode code?

Comment: I do not see some instructions for to set the address of the data segment into the DS segmentregister. Because "mov ax,[bx]" get a word from the location of DS:BX.

Comment: @RossRidge Unfortunately it is not.

Comment: @DirkWolfgangGlomp It is not necessary.

Answer (score 2):

The assembly code looks generally alright. You might want to check the interrupt calling sequences against the order of parameters on the stack by setting a breakpoint right on the `int 10h` and checking the register values. I haven't done that stuff for well over 20 years, and I'm rusty.

You have at least two probable operator precedence problems. I don't think these do the right thing.

```
element = element & (1 << offset) >> offset;
current = getPixelBlock((uchar)counter/8);
```

You have a hard-coded 'magic number': 21. I have no idea what that means.

After that, the question is: where did it crash? Time to get that debugger stoked up and paying for itself.

---

I meant to ask: why on earth write this stuff in assembly? You can easily call `int 10h` either directly from C, from embedded asm in C, or by a single wrapper function.

Comment: Can you advice good debugger for DOS(I know 2[afdpro, td] debuggers, but it's impossible to debug C code in ASM debugger)? Operator problem(first) isn't so important(in the worst case I would have only black points) now. And second operator problem isn't problem at all. 21 is size of the qrCode. It doesn't crash, it goes to infinite loop, and draws only first point. The task is to use assembly "library" in C program. This is homework, so I have no freedom of choice.

Comment: It used to be called DEBUG, but this ain't MS-DOS, this is DOSbox. It comes with a debugger. Time to learn how to use it.

Comment: I have read man-page for DOSbox, but I have not found anything about debugging... What I'm doing wrong? And even if I found it how should I debug assembly with strings like `DB 66H`? I mean there wouldn't any `CALL` or `PUSH` or `POP`, also GCC compiles ALL variables to use in stack, maybe you'll advice what optimization to set?

Comment: This is something you should ask at school, not here. This link might help: http://kannan.jumbledthoughts.com/index.php/howto-use-dosbox-as-a-quick-dirty-disassembler/

Answer (score 0):

The way you define your data with a trailing comma introduces an extra byte with zero value. At least in my assembler!

I think you need to double the value of CURRENT in the DRAWLOGO function in order to synchronize with the data.

The function GETPIXELBLOCK recieves values from 0 To 55 which is 1 more than the data lines available!